# Hide Submit button when particular div element is loaded in the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following html code and this is a part of the html

```
<div id="mount"
 <span> please wait while we are loading...</span>
</div>
```

and I have a main submit button

```
<div id="MainContentbutton" class="buttonscontainer" data-kaction="submitdiv" style="display:block";>

 <input type="submit" name="MainContentbtnsubmit" value="submit" id="MainContentbtnsubmit"
 class="submitbutton" onbeforesubmit="Application_onbeforeSubmit" data-kaction="submit" style="font-weight:bold;>
<div>
```

I wanted to hide the button by using

```
display:none
```

and this should hide only when the following div is loaded.

```
 div id="mount"
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process.

Comment: Do they share the same container?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: What do you mean from div is loaded? Divs are being loaded when the page is being rendered and you can place the script right after the div. elsewhere If there is an image or other external resources, you should care about resource loading.

Comment: @sm3sher They share a different div elements.

Comment: @dippas I have tried as below 
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $("#MainContentbtnSubmit").hide();}); But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your Js file or wherever you load the data when the result comes in you can do it like this:

```
// this function is to fake the loading 
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

delay(1000).then(() {

  var mount = document.getElementById('mount');
  var submitButton = document.getElementById('MainContentbtnsubmit');

  mount.css({'display' : 'none'});
  submitButton.css({'display' : 'block'});

});
```

Don't forget to set the display of the button to none, in line css.

Comment: I have tried like this  
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){ document.getElementbyId('MainContentbtnsubmit').style.display='none'   } );
</script>

but it is not working.